# How to redirect to Dashboard after WordPress login?

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress site allows me to signin but presented with a message on the wp-admin page:

```
There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

I have already tried removing all plugins.
My site does have an .htaccess file.

Comment: in wp_config.php add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: This message itself does'nt give us anything to go on so you'll need to do a bit more debugging yourself. Turn on debugging as Dimitry suggested, and make sure you check the admin email (including spam!) to see what the email said - that will usually tell you what's going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306626/how-to-redirect-to-dashboard-after-wordpress-login#comment110214718_62306626) mentioned, the admin email revealed the broken plugin.